# How to accumulate the lengths of a list of real-valued intervals?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I write a function that takes a list of intervals (as sorted float pairs) as input and returns the sum of the lengths of the intervals?

For example, `[[1,2],[3,5],[6,9]]` has three intervals of length 1, 2 and 3 respectively.  So the sum is 6.

Comment: [tag:python-requests] is for a specific HTTP client library

Comment: Could you provide an example of input and expected output for your function?

Comment: @machfour example: list( [[3,4], [12, 16] ] ) return 5

Comment: That is a list of lists, not a list of spaces.

Comment: this is a list of intervals

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you actually wanted was to get the sum of differences for each sublist:

```
def foo(list_of_spaces):
  return sum([abs(x[0]-x[1]) for x in list_of_spaces])
foo([[3,4], [12, 16] ]) # 5
```

If you want to allow negative values then remove abs (and then the order of the sublist will matter)

---

Using `len` you can do it like this:

```
def foo(list_of_spaces):
    return sum([len(x) for x in list_of_spaces])
```

`[len(x) for x in list_of_spaces]` gives you a list of integers, the length of each string.

`sum([len([j for j in x if j is " "]) for x in list_of_spaces])` would only count spaces.

Comment: how to input the list with the intervals?

Comment: I want to create a function that will accept as an entry a list of intervals and return the sum of the length of the intervals. For example: list ([[3,4], [12, 16]]) return 5

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to do that...look at the top of my answer @R.Monkey

Comment: I want you to show me the way the user will be able to give the list of intervals. something like thta: MyList = input ("give me a list")

Comment: sorry if I misunderstood you just am very beginner and I do not understand them easily

Comment: Parsing user input is a different question. You should mark this or some other answer as the answer and ask about user input as a separate question